# PHPUnit error: Missing argument 1 for with dataProvider

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the below test script:

```
class testTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function provider() {
        return [
            [1,false],
            [2,true]
        ];
    }

   /**
    * @test
    * @provider provider
    */
    public function test_test($num, $expected) {
        $actual = $num%2 ? false : true;
        $this->assertEquals($actual, $expected);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this I get the error:

```
1)  testTest::test_test
Missing argument 1 for testTest::test_test()
```

I have other tests in my test suit that are not using dataProviders and they are working fine. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Can you paste whole class? But first, try changing data providers methods name from `testDataProvider` to `provider` (also change name in annotation)

Comment: Please check the update. Changed testDataProvider to provider as you suggested but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@provider` to `@dataProvider`, e.g.

```
/**
* @dataProvider provider
*/
public function test_test($num, $expected) {
    $actual = $num%2 ? false : true;
    $this->assertEquals($actual, $expected);
}
```

Read the documentation:
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.dataProvider

---

PS: you've got the arguments the wrong way round in your assertEquals. It should be:

```
$this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
```

Again: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals